# Angular 7 - synchronous http requests

Tags: get, request, angular7, synchronous

I'm collecting data from wordpress api and pushing them to an array using few requests after button click which runs **initGetComments()** function.

**Arrays:**

```
  singleCommentResults: CommentsItem[] = [];
  commentsResults = [];
```

**Init function:**

```
  initGetComments(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("comment_btn");

    if (!btn.classList.contains('clicked')){
      var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('single-post');

      for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ) {
        this.getComments(posts[i].id).subscribe(data => {
          this.singleCommentResults = data;
          this.commentsResults.push(this.singleCommentResults[0]);
          console.warn("commentsResults =", this.commentsResults);
        })
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Comments already downloaded!')
    }

    btn.classList.add("clicked");
  }
```

**getting function:**

```
  getComments(ID:string): Observable<CommentsItem[]> {
    console.log(ID);

    return this.http
      .get(`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/en.blog.wordpress.com/posts/${ID}/replies/?number=1`)
      .map(res =>
        res.comments.map(
          item =>
            new CommentsItem(
              item.post.ID,
              item.ID,
              item.author.name,
              item.author.avatar_URL,
              item.date,
              item.raw_content
            )
        )
      );
  }
```

At this moment all those requests are send at "same time" and I would like to send each of them when the previous one has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function as follows to achive it:

Init Function: Changed

```
initGetComments(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("comment_btn");

    if (!btn.classList.contains('clicked')){
      var posts = document.getElementsByClassName('single-post');

      // Call to new function to fetch comments for first post
      this.getSyncComment(0, posts)

    } else {
      console.log('Comments already downloaded!')
    }

    btn.classList.add("clicked");
}
```

New function to fetch comment synchronously

```
getSyncComment(n, posts){
    if (n == posts.length) {
    return 
    }


    this.getComments(posts[n].id).subscribe(data => {
        const singleCommentResults = data; // Changed
        this.commentsResults.push(singleCommentResults[0]); // Changed
        console.warn("commentsResults =", this.commentsResults);

        // Make recursive call to fetch comment for next post
        this.getSyncComment(n+1, posts);
      });
  }
```